# SQL query. Need to GROUP BY the combination of values in two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, case

So I have two tables. One with amount of shares that people have:

```
Person_ID ||  Shares
1         ||  100
2         ||  150
3         ||  315
4         ||  75
5         ||  45
...
```

and another with info whether a person is present (there are two columns specifying that) and what group does he belongs to:

```
Person_id || barcode_presence || manual_presence || group_id
1         || NULL             || 1               || NULL
2         || 1                || NULL            || 1
3         || 1                || 0               || 2
4         || 0                || NULL            || 1
5         || 1                || 0               || 1
...
```

I need to find out the sum of all present and sum of all absent shares in every single group (NULL group is also a group).

The thing I cannot figure out is that whether the person is present or absent is figured out by the combination of two columns (barcode_presence and manual_presence):

if manual_presence = 1   --> present

else if (manual_presence = NULL and barcode_presence = 1)     --> present

everything else is absent.

Thats what i've got so far.

```
SELECT  presence_list.Person_id, presence_list.person_name, 
presence_list.barcode_presence, presence_list.manual_presence,
presence_list.group_id, people_data.Share 
, sum(people_data.Share)

FROM presence_list

INNER JOIN people_data
ON presence_list.Person_id = people_data.Person_ID

WHERE meeting_id = 1 AND voting_id = 0 
GROUP BY presence_list.group_id,  
barcode_presence,
manual_presence
ORDER BY presence_list.group_id
;
```

But obviously that does not give me the desired result. it groups by every possible combination of group_id, barcode_presence and manual_presence like following:

```
Person_id || barcode_presence || manual_presence || group_id || share || sum(shares)
1         || NULL             || 1               || NULL     || 100   || 100
2         || 1                || NULL            || 1        || 150   || 150
4         || 0                || NULL            || 1        || 75    || 75
5         || 1                || 0               || 1        || 45    || 45
3         || 1                || 0               || 2        || 315   || 315
```

So i'm looking for a way to (in this case) connect person with id 4 and 5, because they are both absent and they are from the same group, like this:

```
Person_id || barcode_presence || manual_presence || group_id || share || sum(shares)
1         || NULL             || 1               || NULL     || 100   || 100
2         || 1                || NULL            || 1        || 150   || 150
5         || 1                || 0               || 1        || 45    || **120**
3         || 1                || 0               || 2        || 315   || 315
```

I've tried using `HAVING` clause but I didn't found a way for it to handle complex expressions like `manual_presence = 1 OR (manual_presence is null AND barcode_presence = 1)`

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated! thanks beforehand!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 2):

if only one of the two columns can ever be populated, Use coalesce...

```
 Group By group_id, Coalesce(barcode_presence, manual_presence)
```

if not, (can, say, the barcode_presence = 1 and the presence = 0?), then yu need to decide what groups of possible combinations of values you want to group by, and just group by an expression that does that...    drawing a chart of value combinations may help...

```
                barcode value     
 manual     Null      0        1
   Null     GrpA    GrpA     GrpB
     0      GrpC    GrpC     GrpB
     1      GrpB    GrpB     GrpB
```

say you want to group by those where both are 0, and all the others, then you would write...

```
 Group By group_id, case When isnull(barcode_presence, 0) = 0 
                          And isnull(manual_presence, 0) = 0 Then 0 Else 1 End
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` to make a group for present and non-present people:

```
select  group_id
,       case 
        when barcode_presence = 1 and manual_presence = 1 then 1
        else 0
        end
,       sum(share)
from    presence_list pl
join    people_data pd
on      pl.person_id = pd.person_id
group by 
        group_id
,       case 
        when barcode_presence = 1 and manual_presence = 1 then 1
        else 0
        end
order by 
        group_id
```

Comment: Thats a good solution, thanks! I ended up using another one, but nonetheless this one was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think producing two columns is the way to go:

```
select pd.group_id,
       SUM(isPresent * pd.shares) as PresentShares,
       SUM((1 - isPresent)*pd.shares) as NotPresentShares
from (select pl.*,
             (case when manual_presence = 1 or 
                        manual_precence is null and barcode_presence = 1
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as IsPresent
           end
      from presence_list pl
     ) pl join
     people_data pd
     on pl.Person_id = pd.Person_ID
group by pd.group_id
```

The subquery just applies your logic to create a flag that is 1 for present and 0 for not-present.  Conveniently, when coded this way, "1 - IsPresent" is 1 for not-present and 0 for present.

This value then used in the aggregation to aggregate the shares.  You could have the outer query be:

```
select group_id, IsPresent, sum(pd.shares)
from . . .
group by group_id, IsPresent
```

If you really wanted the values on separate rows.

Comment: Great solution! That is exactly what i need, however, I've encoutered a problem and I'm quite puzzled about it. Thats what the script outputs.

<br/>
Group_id || PresentShares || NotPresentShares<br/>
5  || 3380   || 10140<br/>

However, I know for a fact that there are only 2 people in Group 5 and each of them has exactly 3380 shares.

Any idea why it counted NotPresentShares 3 times?